# Faithful Representation of von Neumann Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

I have questions regarding part of [E. Christopher Lance. **Ergodic Theorems for Convex Sets and Operator Algebras**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01390319), Page 205.

I am looking for a good reference explaining how the faithful representation $\pi_{\rho}$ is given.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, as $\pi_\rho$ is defined explicitly in the page you linked.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I am looking for a good reference explaining how the faithful representation $\pi_{\rho}$ is defined.

Comment: You mean the GNS representation? It is explained in any book on C$^*$-algebras and/or von Neumann algebras.

Comment: @MartinArgerami if you don't mind https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240532/convergence-in-the-strong-topology-in-von-neumann-algebras